# Integrated Security in a Talend

Tags: sql-server, talend

Rather than specifying userid/password, I want my Windows credentials to flow into SQL.
I am thinking about using an Context variable to do this but don't know much details about the implementation.

Can someone guide me through this process if you have worked with this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) to do this?

Talend has LDAP components that can read (and edit) data from an LDAP schema including Active Directory but you would be unable to retrieve the password from there as it is hashed.

Instead you can supply the job with context variables of the domain username and password that you use but these would have to be manually set. You'll need to create 2 context variables that are available to the job (for example "username" and "Password" giving them a type of `String` and `Password` respectively - `Password` is simply a string but it can be obscured by Talend during the process. It won't transmit it securely however).

To then use these context variables in the connection to SQL Server you simply set the "Username" to context.username and "Password" to context.password. If you properly add the context variables to your job you should be able to see these variables by hitting ctrl+space on the fields.

You can then load the value for the context variable at run time either by passing it as a parameter to the job or by having the job load all of its context variables at run time from a file or database.